# Hide bootstrap popover exclude target element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I can't seem to figure out how to not hide a popover when clicking subsequent times on the trigger element.

I have:

```
$('.vote').click(function() {
    $.post(ROOT + 'call', {call: 'Cake->vote'}, function(data) {
        $('.vote').attr('data-content', data.msg);
        if (!$('.popover').css('display'))
        {
            $('.vote').popover('show');
        }
    }, 'json')
})
```

And the HTML:

```
<img class="vote" width="32" src="/images/down_red_empty.png" data-placement="right" data-content="" data-html="true">
```

And my attempt to hide it that doesn't work:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if ($('.popover').has(e.target).length == 0 && $(e.target).is('.vote') === false) {
        $('.vote').popover('hide');
    }
});
```

It seems to be ignoring `$(e.target).is('.vote') === false` completely

Comment: Can you create a http://www.bootply.com/ demonstrating the issue?

Answer (score 0):

See a working example here: http://www.bootply.com/110602 (it uses `setTimeout` instead of a `$.post` call).

A few issues with the code:

The `$('.vote').click` should in fact be `$(document,'.vote').click`.

As you are manually toggling the popover, you should set the data-trigger tag in the `img` to be `data-trigger='manual'`. This means you control what happens when you click on the item with the popover, otherwise a click will display or hide the popover by default.

Lastly, instead of `.is('.vote')` you should use `.hasClass('vote')`, as it is the CSS class you are using as a condition.

```
  $(document, '.vote').click(function() {
    $.post(ROOT + 'call', {call: 'Cake->vote'}, function(data) {
       $('.vote').attr('data-content', data.msg);
       if (!$('.popover').css('display'))
       {
           $('.vote').popover('show');
       }
    }, 'json')
  });

  $(document).click(function(e) { 
    if ($('.popover').has(e.target).length == 0 && !$(e.target).hasClass('vote')) {
        $('.vote').popover('hide');
    }
  });
```

and the HTML:

```
<img class="vote" width="32" src="/images/down_red_empty.png" data-trigger="manual" data-placement="right" data-content="" data-html="true">
```